# Dump verilog array in gtkwave

Tags: verilog, wave

Is there a way to dump the memory in verilog using vcd dump?
Since now i have written this:

```
module sampler(clk, pixel);

    input clk;
    input[7:0] pixel;

    wire[7:0] pixel;
    reg [7:0] macro_block [0:63];
    reg [5:0] address;

    always @ (posedge clk or negedge clk) begin
        macro_block[address]=pixel;
        address<=address+1;
    end
endmodule

module tb();

    reg clk;
    reg[7:0] pixel;

    sampler s(clk,pixel);

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("test.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0,tb);
        clk=0;
        pixel=1;
        $monitor("%g %b",$time, clk);
        #5 $finish;
    end

    always begin
        #1 clk <= ~clk;
    end

endmodule
```

but the array `macro_block` is not shown in gtkwave, is it possible to shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your simulator.  For Icarus, I think you need an explicit dumpvars statement for every array row you want to dump.  I don't recall if you need the [msb:lsb] subscript.  For CVC, you can use the +dump_arrays plusarg.  I use CVC all the time and view arrays in gtkwave.